# find other attributes of a class name in a element

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece  of code:

```
<div class="_GAb-_GAd">
    <div class="_GANmb _GAe ACTION-removeFilter TARGET-1">clear</div>
</div>

<div class="_GAb-_GAd">
    <div class="_GANmb _GAe ACTION-removeFilter TARGET-2">clear</div>
</div>
```

and the script (Jquery)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ACTION-removeFilter").click(function() {
            alert('find out which TARGET is being clicked.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to know which TARGET is being clicked (TARGET-1 or TARGET-2). Is there a way to find out?

How will I know it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `regex` on className

```
var target = $(this).attr('class').match(/\b(TARGET-[^ ]+)/)[1];
```

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/mU0sM6/4)

1. `\b`: Word Boundary
2. `()`: Capturing Group. Can be accessed by using second index(1) of array
3. `TARGET-`: Matches `TARGET-` literally
4. `[^ ]*`: `^`: Not. Matches anything that is not space, zero or more times.

**Note**: To match case-insensitively use `i` flag. I assumed that there will always be something after `-` so used `+`.

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ACTION-removeFilter").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('class').match(/\b(TARGET-[^ ]+)/)[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_GAb-_GAd">
  <div class="_GANmb _GAe ACTION-removeFilter TARGET-1">clear</div>
</div>

<div class="_GAb-_GAd">
  <div class="_GANmb _GAe ACTION-removeFilter TARGET-2">clear</div>
</div>

<div class="_GAb-_GAd">
  <div class="_GANmb _GAe ACTION-removeFilter TARGET-My_Beautiful_class_488">Check this</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regex perect for TARGET-1 or TARGET-2. What if it contains TARGET-XYZXYZ or TARGET-ABC-XYX-QIE.

Comment: @Venkat I assume there will always be number, now used space to delimit the class name. Check the update.

Comment: @Venkat Welcome :) Glad to help

Comment: The Run code snippet however doesnot work in my google chrome browser.

Comment: @Venkat works for me, open browser console and check if there is any error